# I don't understand where I should put my 2 inputs in this while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
initial_energy = int(input())
won = 0
command = ''

while initial_energy >= 0 and command != 'End of battle':
    distance = int(input())
    if initial_energy >= distance:
        initial_energy -= distance
        won += 1
        if won % 3 == 0:
            initial_energy += won
    elif initial_energy < distance:
        print(f'Not enough energy! Game ends with {won} won battles and {initial_energy} energy')
    else:
        command = input()
print(f'Won battles:{won}. Energy left:{initial_energy}')
```

The goal of the program is that you receive energy and try to kill enemy who is in a certain distance that you receive as an input. The distance is how much energy you need to kill the enemy. If you kill it you get a win. Every 3 wins you gain energy equal to the amount of wins you have. You do this until you get a command "End of battle" or you run out of energy.
Edit: Also you lose energy when you try to kill enemies if that wasn't clear from the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your code game doesn't end if `initial_energy` less than `distance` you need to add `break` statement. You can change the `command` input to first if condition there is no need of `else` condition because you ask `command` input only if you won.

```py
initial_energy = int(input("Energy: "))
won = 0
command = ''

while initial_energy >= 0 and command != 'End of battle':
    distance = int(input("distance: "))
    if initial_energy >= distance:
        initial_energy -= distance
        won += 1
        if won % 3 == 0:
            initial_energy += won
        command = input("command: ")
    else:
        print(f'Not enough energy! Game ends with {won} won battles and {initial_energy} energy')
        break
print(f'Won battles:{won}. Energy left:{initial_energy}')
```